# How can the amplitude of a scattered wave be greater than the amplitude of the incident wave (at resonance)?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, waves, acoustics, scattering

When waves are scattered at resonance, the amplitude of the scattered wave can be much greater than the incoming wave. But where is the energy coming from that allows the increased amplitude of the scattered wave?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the kind of situation you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a specific example it's hard to answer this question, but generally speaking resonance when it exists in a system tends to amplify energy at the specific resonant frequency. Conservation of energy applies so what you may see is that energy is drawn from other frequency bands and or locations in the system to concentrate energy within the space where resonance occurs.